# chrome://inspect/#devices shows device but no open chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, adb, chrome-remote-debugging

I am trying to debug my web application. In the `chrome://inspect/#devices` tab I can see my device and in adb devices too, the problem is that the chrome tabs that I open on the mobile are not shown.

I have USB debugging enabled.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you called `WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);`?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I explained myself wrong. I only need to inspect the html of my mobile web page. The open tabs should appear in chrome mobile, but nothing appears.
I was always able to inspect urls without calling WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

Comment: As far as I know Chrome for Android app by default sets this parameters so you can debug your web page when it is shown in Chrome. But if you use a WebView in your own app you have to manually call `setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)`

Comment: Same issue. I can’t see any tabs from chrome. This happens only on my device using a custom ROM (android 11). Other devices using OEM ROM work. What is your android version and do you use a custom ROM ? I suspect a Lineage bug or limitation somehow.

Comment: Same for me, problem happens on a device with custom rom,  works fine on another device with stock OEM rom.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in chrome with this message :

> ⚠ Remote browser is newer than client browser. Try `inspect fallback` if inspection fails.

Solved with inspecting in Google Chrome Canary :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chrome.canary&hl=fr&gl=US&pli=1